# How to update number from an input

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a basic web app in React and I am trying to update an integer from a number type input.

The process is fairly easy but I cannot figure out how to update regarding this process,

let's say we have this hook,

`const [fee, setFee] = useState(2);` // default value of fee should be 2

```
handlerFunc() {
 // ...
}
```

`<input type="number" onChange={handerFunc} />` which should update the fee

and this `<p>Fee is{fee}$</p>` should increment one by one after every 500 number is entered in that number type input.

- 1 for the additional 500 number in the input  => 3 fee.
  note: The fee should stay 2 until the input number reaches 1999 and for every additional 500 types in the input, the fee should also increment by 1.

How can I implement this handler function regarding this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried directly if this works as expected but the logic should be this way:

Keep the fee state in synch with the input.

```
<input type="number" onChange={e => setFee(parseInt(e.target.value,10))} value={fee} />
```

then store a value in a userRef.

```
const calculatedFee = useRef(0);
```

Use useEffect to implement your logic when the fee state change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(fee === 500){ // or whatever condition you need
    calculatedFee.current = 500 // or a calculated amount.
  }
}, [fee]);
```

display the calculatedFees using the ref value;

```
<p>{calculatedFee.current}</p>
```

here is a full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-star-u4o9x?file=/src/App.js